# Много ref на один объект?

Tags: latex

Вопрос: Как ссылаться много раз на одну метку?

Например:

> Процесс нахождения всех простых импликант системы частично
>   определенных булевых функций проиллюстрирован таблицей: **\ref{lb5}**
>   В таблице **\ref{lb5}** ….
>
> …
>
> В табл **\ref{lb5}**
>
> …
>
> **\label{lb5}**

Answer (score 2):

Ваш вопрос не особо понятен.  Ведь всё работает:

```tex
\section{Раздел 1}

Процесс нахождения всех простых импликант системы частично определенных
булевых функций проиллюстрирован таблицей \ref{tab:lb5}.  В таблице
\ref{tab:lb5} (…).

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ l c r }
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
  7 & 8 & 9 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Таблица булевых функций}
\label{tab:lb5}
\end{table}

\section{Раздел 2}

(…) В табл. \ref{tab:lb5} (…).  (…)

\section{Раздел 3}

(…) В табл. \ref{tab:lb5} (…).  (…)
```

Результат:

[image]